# Couldn't get the response from SNMPsim

Tags: python, snmp

I install the SNMPsim on my site. And I convert the file to the format of .snmprec. When I start the sim, I found an error "Variation module 'writecache' referenced but not loaded" when I get a request from the "iftable".

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.1|2:writecache|value=1
```

This is my command to start SNMPsim.

```
C:\Python27\scripts\snmpsimd.py --data-dir=C:/Workspace/walkfile --agent-udpv4-endpoint=192.168.*.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Ilya Etingof.

In the log, we can find scanning "\Users\user name\SNMP Simulator\Variation" directory for variation modules...
But the directory does not exist,
Just need to copy the variation in the scanning folder, the problem will be resolved.

Comment: You should accept your own answer. Another option is to use `--variation-modules-dir=<dir>` switch of `snmpsimd.py` to serve the variation modules from a specific folder, so that you don't need to copy files around.